# Unable to read email attachments in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I have a requirement to read email body and attachments from blackberry application. I am able to read plain text messages, email messages but unable to read the attachments. I am getting null pointer exception when trying to read the attachment stream. I am able to get the content type, size and attachment name but not the content. Below is the sample code I have been playing with. Please help me as I am unable to proceed further

```
public void uploadAttachment(SupportedAttachmentPart attachment)
{
  String strMimeType = attachment.getContentType();
  String strAttachmentFileName=attachment.getFilename();
  String strAttachmentSize=attachment.getSize()
  InputStream emailAttachmentStream = attachment.getInputStream();
  int ch = emailAttachmentStream.read();      
  while(ch!=-1)
  {
   reqVector.addElement((byte) (ch));                                        
   ch = emailAttachmentStream.read();
  }
  }
```

Comment: can anyone help on this. I am stuck and unable to proceed further :(

Answer (score 1):

In BlackBerry, for performance resons, there was a file size limitation regarding attachments, so only a portion of the message was downloaded. The attachments were not actually delivered to the device unless the user opened them.

Now, in JDE 5.0, they introduced a new class, [`AttachmentDownloadManager`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/AttachmentDownloadManager.html), that allows the programmer to force a retrieval from code.

It could be something like this (not tested):

```
Message m = ... //The mail message instance.
AttachmentDownloadManager atm = new AttachmentDownloadManager();
BodyPart[] bparr = atm.getAttachmentBodyParts(m);
atm.download(bparr, <some folder path>, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. I am able to download the attachemnt to the device and then read the stream from it. But, I am facing one more issue.I am displaying a progress screen (using pushGlobalScreen() method by getting event lock) while the attachment is being downloaded to the device.After the attachment is downloaded I am trying to close the screen (popscreen()) but it is not working. The screen is not getting popped from display stack and unable to receive any events. Please let me know the issue and the solution for it.

Comment: It is a different issue, maybe you could post another question and paste your code. You could try `UiApplication.invokeLater` for your GUI-related code, as the one closing screen.